# Abordagem Bottom Up em Data Warehouse

Tags: banco-de-dados, data-warehouse

Dentro do contexto de Data Warehouse(DW), gostaria de saber:

> Por que é correto afirmar que essa abordagem(Bottom Up) não garante padronização dos metadados, podendo criar inconsistências de dados entre os Data Marts(DM).

[Encontrei um artigo](https://canaltech.com.br/infra/a-abordagem-top-down-e-bottom-up-no-data-warehouse-21108/) interessante para explicar como funciona as duas abordagens `Top Down` e `Bottom Up`. Porém não explica a afirmação acima.

A afirmação acima é gabarito de uma [pergunta de prova](https://www.aprovaconcursos.com.br/questoes-de-concurso/questao/558810).

Comment: Nessa questão https://www.gabarite.com.br/questoes-de-concursos/642571-questao relacionada ao assunto a resposta é data mining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na internet consegui encontrar essa justificativa:

> O autor do livro afirma:
>
> > A arquitetura Botton Up proposta de Kimball, chamada de “Bottom Up”, começa com a extração, transformação e a integração dos dados para um ou mais DMs, sendo estes DMs modelados, normalmente através de um modelo dimensional.
> >     Apresenta como pontos positivos, a rápida implementação; a agilidade na apresentação dos resultados e a possibilidade de enfatizar primeiramente os principais setores do negócio.
> >     A principal desvantagem encontrada é a falta de padronização dos data mart’s que pode acarretar em redundância e dados inconsistentes. (MACHADO, 2004).

A afirmação acima fez mais sentido após a leitura [desse artigo](http://en.dwhwiki.info/best_practices/bottom_up) que explica:

> O artigo afirma:
>
> > 1. Os Data Marts são criados de forma **autónoma** e **independente** dos outros Data Mart, ou seja, cada um faz do jeito que bem entende, e certamente isso justifica a falta de padronização.
> > 2. Caso a palavra **inconsistência** seja interpretada como **redundância dos registros**, então é possível afirmar que a falta de padronização gera inconsistência.

Porém não justifica a inconsistência de dados no DW, em virtude do ETL(Extração, Transformação e carga(load) ), citado pelo autor machado.

Uma ilustração que representa a abordagem (Bottom Up)  [image: retirada desse source]
[Imagem retiada dessa fonte](http://dwgeek.com/various-data-warehouse-design-approaches.html/)

Comment: Essa é a resposta da sua pergunta?

Comment: Bom, então seria mais interessante ser uma edição da pergunta, e não resposta. A nao ser que você a aceite como solução, mesmo incompleta.

Comment: ok, irei aceitar a resposta após 2 dias, foi a mensagem que deu aqui, quando tentei aceitar a resposta.